# Insert data into mysql from changable numbers of forms

Tags: php, mysql

From input page I have changeable number of forms sending me data. I made so that each new form have next number.

```
name2
date3
name4
date5
name6
date7
etc...
```

The problem begins when I tried to capture them in in my Db in table with two columns "name" and "date".
This is the code Im using:

```
$i = 1;
while(isset($_POST["name".$i]))
{
    $cantidad = $_POST["name".$i];
    $value = $_POST["date".($i+1)];
    $query = "INSERT INTO `tickets` SET `name` = $cantidad, `date` = $value";
    mysql_query($query);
    $i += 2;
}
```

Basically, since the forms come in pares (name and date) I need them to insert in right order in "name" and "date" column. The thing is for some reason the code doesn't inert.

What do I do wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your code entering in database ? can you show

Comment: I posted a fiddle where you can see the input page. The page work fine, but the it seems that I cannot input the stuff from the forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lznogud,

I have done a few changes to your code and accordingly you need to do some in the php file i.e testProces.php

http://jsfiddle.net/mNkub/

```
$('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
            $('<label for="ticketCantidad"><input type="text" id="ticketCantidad" size="20" name="ticketCantidad[' + i +']" value="" placeholder="Valor de Tickets" /></label>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            //i++;
            $('<label for="ticketValue"><input type="text" id="ticketValue" size="20" name="ticketValue[' + i +']" value="" placeholder="Cantidad de Tickets" /></label><p></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++;
            return false;
    });
```

Now the html structure you get will be

```
<input type="text" id="ticketCantidad" size="20" name="ticketCantidad[2]" value="" placeholder="Valor de Tickets">
<input type="text" id="ticketValue" size="20" name="ticketValue[2]" value="" placeholder="Cantidad de Tickets">
```

then next one will be :

```
<input type="text" id="ticketCantidad" size="20" name="ticketCantidad[3]" value="" placeholder="Valor de Tickets">
<input type="text" id="ticketValue" size="20" name="ticketValue[3]" value="" placeholder="Cantidad de Tickets">
```

and so on

now in the php file you will get two arrays with both fields data in same key in POST. Then you can do the coding as follows :

```
if(isset($_POST["ticketCantidad"]) && count($_POST['ticketCantidad'])>0) {

    foreach($_POST["ticketCantidad"] as $key => $value) {
        $cantidad = $value;
        $value = $_POST["ticketValue"][$key];
        $query = "INSERT INTO `tickets` SET `name` = $cantidad, `date` = $value";
        mysql_query($query);
    }     

}
```

Hope this will clears the picture.

PS : you may need to do some tweaking in code above as i have not tested it, just writing it in one go.

Comment: Oh man, if I can I would hug you:) It worked like a charm. Thanks I million this one was a tough nut to crack!!!

Comment: I am happy i could help.. you can add me on skype for future :) detail on my profile

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you will break the loop after some instance or else it will be infinite loop.

```
$i = 1;
while(true)
{
    if(isset($_POST["name".$i])) {
        $cantidad = $_POST["name".$i];
        $value = $_POST["date".($i+1)];
        $query = "INSERT INTO `tickets` SET `name` = $cantidad, `date` = $value";
        mysql_query($query);
        $i += 1;
    } else {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: @SKV Please check again is it same?

Comment: Yes it will work exactly same, while(isset($_POST["name".$i])) also serves the same purpose and will not be in a infinite loop. try copying and running in a file

Comment: As SKV said its it part of the question, it does prevents the looping but it still doesnt insert data in the database. In any case here is the fiddle of the input page, I hope its its not complicating the question:http://jsfiddle.net/bocacoca/mBxrc/1/

Comment: @SKV is it same? check again, in question if directly break the loop according to its some reference values.